# ggplotly function on ggplot2 object crashes R & RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, plotly

A simple call of `ggplotly()` on a ggplot2 object makes RStudio crash. The simple code is started below.

```
library(plotly)
library(tidyverse)

iris.ggplot <- ggplot(data = iris,
                      aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()

print(iris.ggplot)

ggplotly(iris.ggplot)
```

[image: Screen Short of the Error message]

Comment: add library(ggplot2)

Comment: Hi Govind, ggplot2 is already loaded. Infact, a call to plotly automatically loads, dplyr and ggplot2. For simplification I just stated a very brief extract. Do you know any fixes.

Comment: what the R studio Version ?

Comment: Error related to ggplotly()

Comment: Try with install.packages("plotly", type = "source")

Comment: The current version is Version 1.2.1114